# Gnome-classic, new windows remain buried behind other window

Tags: 11.10, window-manager, gnome-classic, focus

I have recently moved from ARCH Linux to Ubuntu 11.10.

I switched to using Gnome-Classic and noticed strange behaviours with the windows whenever I open them.

I have setup Launchers on the Panel to launch Dolphin, Terminal and Chrome Browser.
Whenever I launch any of these I notice that they open behind the current window that is in-focus instead of coming up in front.

According to me any sane windows manager would by default bring up the new window in front and focus,

Why would you want to open a window hidden behind all other window?

Is there any thing or configuration that I need to check?

Comment: Do you have Focus Follows Mouse, Raise Follows Mouse enabled?